# 2012 Cadillac cts low beam lights do not work

Tags: headlight

2012 Cadillac cts low beam lights do not work.  High beam and daytime running lights work fine.  I changed the bulbs and got the same results.

Comment: Have you checked the fuses, often on many modern cars there are one for each side, but not always...

Comment: Vehicles come with a low beam fuse, and a high beam fuse and from what I've seen some cars are also equipped with a bulb relay... check to see if you're getting power at the end of your wiring harness